# Hosting ASP.NET MVC application on linux using mod_mono + apache in apache root directory

Tags: asp.net, linux, apache, mono, mod-mono

I'm trying to host an ASP.NET .NET4.0 MVC4 application on Centos 6 server.
I have the latest mono, xsp and mod_mono installed. Evertything is configured to run the application using apache web server. I've used [this tool](http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/) for creating a config ("ASP.NET application (i.e., virtual directory)").

Apache's root directory: `var/www/html`.
I've placed my application in a `/var/www/html/Unreal` and config is  configured to use it.
Everything works fine when i'm trying to access the `domainname/Unreal`.

What I need is to place my application in apache's root directory so that it will be accessible simply with a domainname. I tried editing path in mod_mono config i got from the tool, but I had an 403 error saying that opening .config file is forbidden.

I tried making config for a Virtual Host and everything went good. But the problem is: I have a php forum in `/var/www/html/forum` directory and asp.net web server tries to handle it instead of a php.

Is there a way to exclude the forum directory or something else to fix the problem?